# C Array Declarations with Variables?

Tags: c, arrays

I ask the user to input two numbers and I read them in using scanf. I assign these numbers to the variables x and y as such:

```
int x;
int y;
scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
```

Can I then declare a 2D-array using the variables x and y, like such?

```
int array[x][y];
```

Comment: Yes, you can, it's called a variable length array. Any other question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. C99 and latter added this feature called [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf(%d %d, &x, &y);
```

is wrong. It should be

```
scanf( "%d%d", &x, &y);
```

And regarding your real question, yes. On any compiler that supports C99 and newer versions , you can do that. It's alright to do

```
int x;
int y;
scanf( "%d%d ", &x, &y);
int a[x];
int array[x][y];
```

These are all fine on the compilers that support C99 ( like gcc , MinGw , etc ).

This is a feature introduced as [Arrays of Variable Length](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)

Comment: Sorry, yes that is what I had in my code, I just mistyped when writing the question.

Comment: @jsmith102894 so could you edit your question and fix this? It will prevent noise in comments or in answers.